# HTML5 input type=date: Can I open/close the date picker with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to customise the HTML5 input type="date" element. I want to add a separate button clicking which will toggle visibility of the date picker dropdown. I couldn't find any info on this. Any help greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Don't! If you're using a browser default input, let the browser default UI stay! It increases usability by being slightly less terrible than whatever you're going to do.

Comment: Clicking anywhere outside of the calendar dropdown closes it for me, so I'm not sure if you would even need a button.

Comment: he wants the button because he also wants to be able to open it this way :)

Comment: It's OK if there's no separate button. In that case, I'll need to change the look of the triangle icon. Would also like to make it always visible, rather than visible only on hover. Will that be possible?

Comment: if you want it always visible you can do 
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { opacity: 1;  }

Answer (score 12):

Here is Solution I made using CSS.

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.exmp-wrp {
    margin-top: 100px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}

.btn-wrp {
    border: 1px solid #dadada;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

.btn-clck {
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}

.btn-clck::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    right: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 78px;
    height: 40px;
    color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0);
    opacity: 0
}

.btn-clck::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.btn-clck::-webkit-clear-button {
    margin-right:75px;
 }
.btn {
    height: 100%;
    background: #fda200;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="exmp-wrp">
  <div class="btn-wrp">
    <input type="date" class="btn-clck"/>
  </div>
  <button class="btn">Click me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know you can use code snippets on stackoverflow and don't need jsfiddle for this ? https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Yes, Shall I do it that way?

Comment: It is the preferred way by the community, JS Fiddle links are ok, but if JS fiddle ever goes down, about 30% of the links to code from answers are broken.

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="date"]').change(function () {
        closeDate(this);
    });

});

function closeDate(dateInput) {
    $(dateInput).attr('type', 'text');
    $(dateInput).attr('type', 'date');
}
```

Comment: a non-cross browser solution? :/

Comment: Why are you saying that?