# Display HTML5 native datepicker on button click

Tags: javascript, html, date, datepicker, frontend

In my application I need to allow the user to select a date from a datepicker and handle the selection event to display additional data.

I'd like to use the native HTML5 datepicker which normally pops up when using an `input[type='date']` field.

So I'm wondering if ther's a way to display this datepicker without an input field, or at least hiding the field in the page.

Comment: The best way is to alter the calendar button: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47696360/1762224 I do not think it's possible to programatically open the calendar without clicking on the built-in indicator.

Comment: maybe this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50052571/html-date-input-without-the-date-picker

Comment: Are you trying to programatically send an `F4` event to the hidden input field?